# Difference between {puts a} and {|a| puts a} in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

While I on a Ruby tutorial, i saw them use the second method of printing the whole list, |a| puts a, but i was wondering why they didn't simply type *puts a*, and trying it for myself, using *puts a* prints the list twice and i haven't found why

```
irb(main):001:0> a = ['hello', 'hi']
=> ["hello", "hi"]
irb(main):002:0> a.each {puts a}
hello
hi
hello
hi
=> ["hello", "hi"]
irb(main):03:0> a.each {|a| puts a}
hello
hi
=> ["hello", "hi"]
```

Basically, what's the difference between these two. thanks in advance, and sorry if I'm being a doof

Comment: You can write just `puts a` instead of `a.each { |a| puts a }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a.each {puts a}
```

This means "for each element in array `a`, print array `a`". If your array contains three elements, the array will be printed three times.

This is valid ruby, but incorrect usage of `each`. It's supposed to accept current element in the block parameter (the `|a|`). Doesn't have to be called `a`, can be anything. These lines produce identical results:

```
a.each { |a| puts a }
a.each { |foo| puts foo }
```

In the first line block parameter `a` shadows outer array `a`. That's why two elements of the array are printed instead of the whole array being printed two times.

Comment: ah, thanks for the insight, still a beginner to Ruby so I can be thankful people like you are around :)

Comment: @ThePanMan321: glad to help and I commend the desire to play around, but maaaaaybe next time if you have a question like this, finish the book/tutorial first. Some books are presenting information in a progressively detailed manner. Chances are, the answer is two chapters away. Maybe it's just me, but I value these "aha!" moments, when things click into place. Having someone to hand it to me on a platter steals a part of fun. IMHO (obviously), do what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
a.each {puts a}
```

will return the entire array

while

```
a.each {|a| puts a}
```

is supposed to pass between || each item of the array. It's actually a bad practice to use the same variable in this case. Better do:

```
a.each {|item| puts item}
```

Comment: "will return the entire array" – While this is true, this is terribly misleading. *All three of your examples* will return the entire array, because that's how `each` is defined: it performs the side-effects of the block and then returns its receiver. So, in an answer to the OP's question what the *difference* is, you mention in your first sentence the *one thing* that is the *same*.

Answer (score 0):

@ThePanMan321 : The block is executed once for each array element. Hence in your case, it is executed twice. So the first case is equivalent to

```
a.size.times {puts a}
```

, you get twice the array being printed.

In the second case, the second `a` is *shadowing* the outer `a` denoting the array. Really bad style. It is equivalent to

```
a.each {|goofy| puts goofy}
```

and hence you see each array element only once.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : I wanted to explicitly give equivalent code, which might help the OP to understand better, what is actually going on here.